# FFMPEG outputs a video file without its audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to slice/cut/split a video using FFMPEG (command line).

It works for the video, but not for the audio.

What I mean is:
The resulting video file ('the-video-file-1.mpg') renders video, but there's no sound, as in the original file.

It's like FFMPEG doesn't know how to read or write the AC3 codec (I assume, by looking at the console output).

Any idea how to resolve this?

```
me@my-box:~/backup$ ffmpeg -i the-video-file.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:41:54 the-video-file-1.mpg
ffmpeg version 3.3.3-2~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'the-video-file.mpg':
  Duration: 01:07:07.12, start: 0.230389, bitrate: 4728 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
[mpeg @ 0x55968b869880] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
[mpeg @ 0x55968b869880] ac3 in MPEG-1 system streams is not widely supported, consider using the vob or the dvd muxer to force a MPEG-2 program stream.
Output #0, mpeg, to 'the-video-file-1.mpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1640 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   45284kB time=00:01:06.61 bitrate=5568.5kbits/frame= 2976 fps=2975 q=-1.0 size=   78484kB time=00:02:00.36 bitrate=5341.5kbitsframe= 4013 fps=2671 q=-1.0 size=  101906kB frame=62267 fps=1259 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1472858kB time=00:41:53.98 bitrate=4799.4kbits/s speed=50.8x    trate=5038.6kbits/s speed= 111x    
video:1388209kB audio:77847kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.463944%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input file is a MPEG-2 Program Stream, but `.mpg` is also used for MPEG-1 Program Stream, so that's what ffmpeg defaults to creating.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i the-video-file.mpg -c copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:41:54 -f vob the-video-file-1.mpg
```

Comment: Why would 'vob' work? I'd guess 'copy' would work, as it works on the original file. Anyway thanks! :)